# Await OptionAsync<T> from Language-ext

Tags: c#, .net, functional-programming, language-ext

I am trying to learn c# Language-ext from Paul Louth. I found the type OptionAsync is quite handy as it combines Tasks and Alternatives into one monad, making it a lot easier to work with both.

But I am confused how the await work with OptionAsync. I thought `await OptionAsync<T>` would return an Option, as Task and Option are two orthogonal concepts. I feel I am really awaiting the Option. However, the await OptionAsync would return a T not the Option.

My question is, should I never be in the situatoin where await OptionAsync is needed? How do I deal with the option if it's a None? Should I always use OptionAsync as a monad and never get out, where the optionality is probably handled along with the Task in the monad? There must be reason for the design.

Answer (score 4):

When you 'stack' two monads (like `Task` and `Option`) you get a combination that abstracts the 'effects' from the underlying value(s) contained in it.

For instance, `OptionAsync<int>` indicates that you may or may not have an `int` , asynchronously delivered. *'May or may not'* because of the `Option`, and `'asynchronously delivered'` because of the `Async`. These are the effects.

When you write monadic expression (e.g. with `await`) you operate on the value 'inside' of the monad - i.e. the `T`. In other words, you've now abstracted away the effects so that you can focus on working on the value. I don't really know LanguageExt, but I'm assuming that it makes `OptionAsync<T>` awaitable, which you can always do with a monad.

The way `Option` works in general is that if the value isn't there, the entire expression short-circuits so that subsequent expressions don't run. The return value will also be an `AsyncOption` value, and if any one of the values along the way was `None`, the final result will also be `None`.

If you really want to deal explicitly with the `Option` value, just work with `Task<Option<T>>`. The whole point of combining the two into `OptionAsync<T>` is that you don't have to do that - until, perhaps, the very end.

You can convert an `OptionAsync<T>` to a `Task<Option<T>>` with the `ToOption()` method.

`Option` is also known as `Maybe`. With that in mind, perhaps my article [Asynchronous Injection](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/02/11/asynchronous-injection/) is useful. In it, at least, I attempt to explain the underlying concepts.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mark Seemann for the explanation. I think now I got it. If I have a need to get Option<T> then I should use Task<Option<T>>. But mostly I should stay inside OptionAsync<T> and avoid getting out of it. Staying inside monads is really not something I can get used to very quickly.